# IQueryable extension method to generate a SelectListItem list

Tags: c#, nhibernate, extension-methods, iqueryable

I´m working with repositories returning IQueryable object.

So, I created an extension method to return a `SelectListItem` List to use on my views:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Func<T, string> value, Func<T, string> text)
{
    return query.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = text(x), Value = value(x) }).ToList();
}
```

And I call like that:

```
var query = Repository<MyClass>.GetAll(); //Return MyClass IQueryable 
var test = query.ToSelectList(x => x.Property1, x => x.Property2);
```

It works great (returning correct list), but the SQL generated select all property from MyClass . I´d like that only Property1 and Property2 were queried on db.

What Am I missing there?

Comment: This this being generated into SQL using Entity Framework?  The additional columns being selected from the generated SQL is most likely due to the `IQueryable<T>` being passed to you rather than anything within this extension method.

Comment: I´m using NHibernate, I don't know I understood your point

Comment: The IQueryable that you are using prior to calling this method might be generating the SQL selecting additional columns.  Your extension method is potentially fine.

Comment: 1. Repositories shouldn't return IQueryable, it breaks it's point as it returns link to database instead of data itselft. 2. I'm using nHibernate in same scenario but it selects only requested properties. It might be that the call to DB happens before projecting to SelectListItems.

Comment: Ah ok, you're passing that x object to method so you're requesting whole object - ORM takes care of it and returns object with all properties.

Comment: humm, you are right. How is the right way to select that?

Comment: construct value & text on the fly - using properties, this extension method doesn't look good. I don't see another way as whole object will always be requested for func parameter - unless you do another select of needed properties before calling extension method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The passed-in delegates are invoked on the result, `x` after it has been retrieved from the database, so that's why all fields are returned. You can pass in expressions instead and then combine them into one expression:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, object>> value, Expression<Func<T, string>> text)
{
    var valueSrc = getProperty(value);
    var textSrc  = getProperty(text);    
    var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T),"x");
    var type = typeof(SelectListItem);
    var textProp = type.GetProperty("Text");
    var valueProp = type.GetProperty("Value");

    // x.valueSrc
    Expression valueExpr = Expression.Property(x,valueSrc);

    // (x.valueSrc).ToString()
    if (valueExpr.Type == typeof(int))
    {
         var toStringMethod = typeof(int).GetMethod("ToString",Type.EmptyTypes);
         valueExpr = Expression.Call(valueExpr,toStringMethod);
    }

    //x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.textSrc, Value = valueExpr }
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T,SelectListItem>>(
                    Expression.MemberInit(
                        Expression.New(type),
                        Expression.Bind(textProp,Expression.Property(x,textSrc)),
                        Expression.Bind(valueProp,valueExpr)),
                    x);

    return query.Select(lambda).ToList();
}

static PropertyInfo getProperty(LambdaExpression exp)
{
    var body = exp.Body;

    //x => (object) x.Property
    var ue = body as UnaryExpression;
    if (ue != null)
        body = ue.Operand;

    return (PropertyInfo) ((MemberExpression) body).Member;        
}
```

Comment: You can't use `Expression.Convert()` for that. You can use `Expression.Call()` for a method supported by NHibernate, or whatever query provider you are using, to change the `int` to a `string`.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a call to `ToString()` if the property is of type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to select on a new anonymous object with only the properties you need then perform the select that create your SelectListItem

Something like

```
return query.Select(p => new { value = value(p), text = text(p) ).Select(p => new SelectListItem(...) ;
```

Comment: Any idea how to that ?

Comment: It will probably be really difficult to do inside the method because you have 2 functions to contend with, and you need them both to appear in a single select call. You may just need to manually select the new object yourself prior to making the call to your method.

Comment: This answer would not change the columns selected in the generated SQL using EF if the IQueryable created prior accesses those columns.